# Problem based on Latches (Sequential Circuits)

Tags: digital-logic, latch, sequential-logic

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

I want to know:

1. If the truth table for \$ Q_{n+1}\$ and \$\bar Q_{n+1}\$ is correct.
2. I have found out the Reset and \$Q_{n}\$ conditions. However, I see two sets of inputs (\$X=0,\, Y=0\$ and \$X=0,\, Y=1\$) for set condition.
3. What is the invalid input condition?

[image]

Comment: FYI,  Q¯n+1 is incorrect in your table where X=0,Y=1,Qn=0

Comment: @Greg When Y=1 and Qn=0 then Q(n+1)(prime)=1